# Interpretation of two-way clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering

I used the following example code from **latticeExtra** to understand two-way clustering in *R*

```
library(latticeExtra)
data(mtcars)
x  <- t(as.matrix(scale(mtcars)))
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))
row.ord <- order.dendrogram(dd.row)

dd.col <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(x))))
col.ord <- order.dendrogram(dd.col)

library(lattice)

levelplot(x[row.ord, col.ord],
      aspect = "fill",
      scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)),
      colorkey = list(space = "left"),
      legend =
      list(right =
           list(fun = dendrogramGrob,
                args =
                list(x = dd.col, ord = col.ord,
                     side = "right",
                     size = 10)),
           top =
           list(fun = dendrogramGrob,
                args =
                list(x = dd.row,
                     side = "top",
                     size = 10))))
```

and this is what I got

[image]

Joining of both row and column entities make sense to me but I'm confused with different color shades of heatmap.

**Questions**

- Do the Joining of row variables also take into account the column variables and vice versa
- What does mean the different colors in heatmap for different row variables clustering as well as for column variables clustering. Specifically focus on **cyl** and **disp** row variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what you mean by bullet 1. Perhaps an explanation of what the code is doing will help?

You have a data frame (`mtcars`), which you standardise (using the `scale()` function) so that the variables have zero mean and unit variance. This has been performed because the data are measured in different units and you ideally want each variable to contribute equally to the dissimilarity measurements used to form the cluster analysis. Finally, this scaled data frame is converted to a matrix and transposed.

Because you transposed the matrix, the first clustering groups the variables in the original (`mpg`, `cyl` etc) into groups that have similar profiles over the different cars. The ordering implied by this clustering is recorded.

The procedure is repeated on the transpose of `x` so now the clustering is in the more familiar way, finding groups of cars that are similar in terms of the design and performance. Again, the ordering of the data implied by this second clustering is recorded.

Next comes the `levelplot` code. This produces a **heatmap** of the standardised data `x`, but we reorder the matrix using the two orderings generated by the cluster analyses earlier. The colours on the levelplot represent the actual data in each cell of matrix `x`; you have in fact just plotted the matrix but instead of showing the actual data, the individual data points are shown by colours.

That should now explain what the colour scale is; it is showing the mapping from the actual data (the standardised data, zero mean, unit variance) to colours used on the plot. Pink colours represent lower than average values and blues the opposite. By reordering the data plotted, we emphasise the group structure in the data. The clear pattern is one of two groups of cars, one that is fuel efficient (above average `mpg` etc and lower `cyl`) shown in the lower rows of the levelplot. The upper rows are the sportier, less efficient cars with larger engines and higher fuel consumption.

To the best of my knowledge, such a plot is not possible with **ggplot2**.

Answer (score 1):

The colours are fairly simple: Blue means more, purple means less, when compared to the distribution of theat variable across all the cars.

So for `cyl` there are three possibilities: 8 (light blue), 6 (pale pink) and 4 (purple).

Similarly for `disp` the Lincoln Continental and Chrysler Imperial have over 400 so are blue while the Toyota Corolla, Fiat 128, Fiat X1-9 and Honda Civic have under 80 and are purple.

As for the clustering, the rows are clustered using the column variables, so those cars with similar values are more likely to be clustered together.  The columns are clustered according to how much similarity there is in the information they give about the cars. Displacement depends on the number of cylinders and the dimensions of each cylinder, so gives similar information to the number of cylinders, and this makes it likely they will be clustered together.

Comment: What does mean by numbers (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3) along colorkey? Does these numbers represent (dis)similarities?

Comment: I would guess these were standard deviations from the mean